# Inno Setup [Dirs] - Permissions flag causes slow install in Windows 10 in some PCs

Tags: windows-10, inno-setup

We are experiencing a strange issue on Windows 10 during installation of our software installer created with Inno Setup 5.5.9.
Attempting to set permissions in the "ProgramData" {commonappdata} folder causes a massive hang in the installer on a small subset of computers.
This entry we can actively reproduce the issue on the computers that experience the hang.

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{commonappdata}\MyFolder"; Permissions: authusers-modify
```

Yet, if I change the setup to this, the issue is not experienced at all:

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{commonappdata}\MyFolder"
```

Any insight, or assistance with the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you change the permissions using `cacl`, do you also experience the delay? Is there any 32-bit vs. 64-bit difference between the machines? Do you use 64-bit install mode? Is there anything useful (any difference) in the installer log file?

Comment: Moving the permissions changes from the installer to a bat file that sets them with icacls, experiences the same issue but seems to take even longer to process.
All machines we have are 64-bit, of the 16 machines, 2 experience this issue.

Comment: So then you should probably ask at [su], a question on permissions in general, not specific to Inno Setup. You will get much wider audience.

Comment: I have also seen this happen and it does not appear to be isolated to Windows 10, as in our observation it happened on Windows Server 2008 (i.e. server equivalent of Windows Vista). In our case it occurred with cacls.exe as well, although using this was much faster than setting the permissions using the Inno Setup native function. In our case there were Gigabytes worth (thousands) of files that were in the folder permissions were being set on. Do you have a similarly large folder in the location your are changing permissions on?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am apparently not receiving email notifications when comments are made to this thread.
To answer your query Robert, after looking, these two users do have gigabytes worth of files in the folders the setup is setting permissions on.

Thank you both for your input.